# A question on mappings on homotopic paths.

Tags: complex-analysis

My Complex Analysis book says that if two paths are homotopic on $\Bbb{C}$ and are on the same side of the origin, then for all $z$ along those two paths, $f(z)$ on the two paths is the same.

I don't know why that is true. Even if the two paths are homotopic, they contain different values of $z$! Hence shouldn't $f(z)$ be different?

The exact quote:

> If we restrict $z$ to any simply connected set $S$ that does not contain the branch point, then every path in $S$ from $p$ to $Z$ will yield the same value of $\sqrt[3]Z$

Comment: Can you include the *exact* quote, with context?

Comment: Certainly, as written the claim is false, as every semicircle in the upper-half plane with center at the origin is homotopic, in which case $f(z)$ would be constant on the entire upper-half plane, which is clearly not true.

Comment: @T.Bongers- I have given the exact quote. Pg. 93 frrom Visual Complex Analysis by Needham. The quote could also mean that the value of $\sqrt[3]{z}$ at $Z$ is the same regardless of which path we take to reach $Z$, but I don't think the author would mention such an obvious fact separately.

Comment: First of all, it is ${\mathbb C}$, not ${\mathbb C}^2$. Second, the theorem your books refers to is the "monodromy theorem/principle", which says that if $f$ is a multivalued analytic function in a simply-connected Riemann surface $S$, such that $f$ is obtained via analytic continuation along paths, then in $S$ there exists a single-valued branch of $f$. In other words, paths which are homotopic rel. their end-points, result in the same value of $f$.